# Boys' Love manhwa in which the main character transmigrated into a book they read and chose to be a butler/assistant to the second male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, webcomics

So I remember seeing this manhwa recommendation on Facebook a while back. I thought I took a screenshot but it seems I didn’t and I can’t remember the name.

Basically, the main character transmigrated/reincarnated into a book they read and so chose to be a butler/assistant to the second male lead to enjoy the cozy life (the second male lead is a chaebol) via the main character's rejected gifts.

However, he’s an omega and has been hiding this fact. One day, while he’s in heat, the second male lead comes in and that’s where the story trailer ends.

Anyone know anything about it? I’ve been searching up large text paragraphs, hoping I’ll catch a glimpse of it, but no luck.

Edit: MC has black/dark blue hair and blue eyes, second ml has brown hair and brown eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not mistaken. This is a promo WEBTOON that just came out. However you can read the web novel online. It’s on Ridi Books, but it does cost money and you need to make an account to purchase the book. It’s called ‘Once again, the second male lead is playing games with me’

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes, a synopsis, or matching points from the question, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).